# How to check utility of indexes in mongo 2.4.14?

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using php and version 2.4.14 of mongodb. I need to reduce indexes to optimize my database. How can I check which indexes I need and which one can I remove?

Answer (score 0):

Actually your question is not clear.
If you are trying to remove and get specific indexes in result. Then, follow the code below.

```
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->dbName;
$collection = $db->collectionName;

$query = array();

$fields = array(
        "_id" =>  FALSE, //if want to remove "_id" index pass false 
        "required_field" => TRUE //if you want "required_field" index pass true
);
$collection->find($query, $fields);
```

Comment: I want to check what indexes I'm actualy using, it's old project and I want to reduce number of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Per-index statistics is not available in MongoDB 2.4.14. However, it is available in MongoDB 3.2.0 and later as an aggregation pipeline stage:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexStats/

Please note that MongoDB 2.4 series is very old and is currently not supported anymore. As of this writing, the oldest supported MongoDB version is the 3.0 series.

Comment: Yeah I know it, but we will be going to 3.2 in next year, I need only to increase speed of our db for few months.